# Elevation accuracy to distinguish maximal gravity anomaly of a sphere with 50% hematite

Tags: geology, geophysics

**Question:** What is the accuracy required in elevation to distinguish the maximal gravity anomaly of a spherical `50%` Haematite (Iron mineral) ore with a radius of `2m` at a depth of `10m` within a shale section.

I'm trying to solve this problem, first we know that the gravity anomaly of a sphere is that of a point mass at the sphere center equal to the product of the density and volume of the sphere, meaning that only the `ρ * V`
product governs the anomaly and neither the size or density can be determined
individually.

Directly above the sphere the maximum anomaly is:
[image]

We know that in order to correct for gravity's elevation we need to use free-air formula which decreases the gravity by 0.3086 mGal for every meter above sea-level.

Haematite density is: `4.9 - 5.3` `(Mg/m^3)`, let's assume we take the lower bound `4.9` for this case.

But we'll be taking only `50%` of `4.9` because only `50%` of the ore has haematite.

Also we know that `R=2m` and `h = 10m`.

I'm still not sure how to continue from here to find the required accuracy in elevation to distinguish the maximal gravity anomaly because I've some questions like what's the other 50% percent of the iron mineral? should we take in consideration that it's the shale section and above it we have the sandstone? and should we just sum the free air/water correction with the Bouguer correction to get the required accuracy? Any help is highly appreciated.

My approach would be to calculate the free air/water correction first:
Depth is 10m which means it's `0.3086 * 10 = 3.086mGal`

And Bouguer correction is: `δgB = 2πGρh = 2π(6.67e-11)(2.45)(-10)` and I took `h=-10m` because it's under the surface.

Should I combine it somehow to `gz_max` I mentioned above?

Comment: @Fred Any ideas how to solve this? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution:**

If `gz_max` is bigger than the air correction then we're done. because we can measure the signal. and we're done. `So gz_max > e_h` is the requirement.

(If the error is bigger than the signal anomaly then we can't measure the signal.)